# How to add a label after a field (Odoo 14)

Tags: xml, odoo

I got an error when trying adding label after a field .

```
  <div>
       <field name="percentage" class="oe_inline"/>
       <label string="%" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The label tag must contain a `for`. You should see the following error:

> Label tag must contain a "for". To match label style without corresponding field or button, use 'class="o_form_label"'.

Try to set the label `for` attribute to `percentage` or use a `span` to show the `%` after the `percentage` field value.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using a div and two label elements. For example, like this:

```
<group style="width:25%">                       
  <label for="percentage" string="Percentage"/>
  <div class="o_row">                         
    <field name="percentage"/>                
    <label for="percentage" string="%"/>      
  </div>                                      
</group>
```